# What's the name of that research that drew the conclusion that rent prices are increasing because people work more from home?

Tags: reference-request, inflation, rent

If you have other articles on the field, please share.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the one where [advertised rents declined sharply, particularly for apartments in Sydney and Melbourne](https://www.rba.gov.au/publications/bulletin/2020/sep/the-rental-market-and-covid-19.html) due to COVID? ;) May be worth to be a bit more specific: country, area, residential vs commercial / office...

Comment: Sorry, was talking about US :)
Residential.